bertrand duopoly with discrete price
There are 2 firms, engaging in price competition. Total costs are $C_A(q)=10q$ and $C_B(q)=21q$ and the inverse demand is $P(q)=120-q$.

What is the equilibrium profits?
What is the maximum amount that firm $A$ would be willing to pay to firm $B$ to exit the market and the minimum amount that firm $B$ would accept to exit the market?

So the marginal costs are $c_A=10$ and $c_B=21$. I assume that the price of firm $A$ is $21-1=20$. Then the $P(q)= 120 - q =20 \Rightarrow q = 100$.
And the profit of firm $A$ is $(p-c)q = (20-10)\times 100 = 1000$.
Is this the right approach to solve this question?

Hey man you wrote under your other question that you will read the meta post, but you still seem to be violating most of its points? Your Q contains specific numbers and is a scan of a question. Also, if you want to improve it instead of reposting you can edit the earlier version.

My bad. I did not read the last part.

By "discrete price", I assume both firms can charge price from the set of non-negative integers.

Define the players as $N = \{A,B\}$
Price competition
Action set of both players = $\mathbb{Z_+}$
Assuming simultaneous move game and perfect information to both players
Quantity demanded is : $Q^d(P) =120 -P $
$C_A(Q_A) = 10Q_A $
$C_B(Q_B) = 21Q_B$

Since both firms compete in prices, the firms that set lower prices gets quantity demanded as per the demand function and if prices are equal, I assume both firms share the quantity demanded equally at that price. Profits in this Bertrand duopoly can be defined as:-
$\pi_i(P_i,P_j)$ = $\left\{\begin{matrix}
0& \text{if}\: P_i >P_j \\ 
P_i .\frac{Q^d(P_i)}{2}- C_i(\frac{Q^d(P_i)}{2})& \text{if}\: P_i =P_j  \\
P_i {Q^d(P_i)}- C_i(Q^d(P_i))& \text{if}\: P_i <P_j 
\end{matrix}\right.$
where $i,j \in \{A,B\} \: \text{but} \: i\neq j$
This will yield:-
$\pi_A(P_A,P_B)$ = $\left\{\begin{matrix}
0& \text{if}\: P_A >P_B \\ 
\frac{(P_A -10)(120-P_A)}{2}& \text{if}\: P_A =P_B  \\
(P_A -10)(120-P_A)  & \text{if}\: P_A <P_B 
\end{matrix}\right.$
and
$\pi_B(P_A,P_B)$ = $\left\{\begin{matrix}
0& \text{if}\: P_B >P_A \\ 
\frac{(P_B -21)(120-P_B)}{2}& \text{if}\: P_B =P_A  \\
(P_A -21)(120-P_B)  & \text{if}\: P_B <P_A 
\end{matrix}\right.$
Best Response $BR_i(P_j) $ of $i^{th}$ firm can be found by solving following optimisation problem :-
$ \underset{P_i \in \mathbb{Z_+}}{max} \: \pi_i(P_i,P_j)$
This yields (on solving for $i \in \{A,B\}$):-
$BR_A(P_B)$ = $\left\{\begin{matrix}
\{65\}& \text{if} \:  P_B >65 \\ 
\{P_B-1\}  & \text{if} \: P_B \in \{12,13,14...,65\}  \\
\{11 \}  & \text{if} \: P_B =11   \\
\{a \in \mathbb{Z_+}| a \geq 10 \}  & \text{if} \: P_B =10  \\
\{ a \in \mathbb{Z_+}| a > P_B \} & \text{if} \: P_B <10 
\end{matrix}\right.$
$BR_B(P_A)$ = $\left\{\begin{matrix}
\{70,71\}& \text{if} \: P_A > 71  \\ 
\{70\}  & \text{if} \: P_A =71  \\
\{P_A -1 \}  & \text{if} \: P_A \in \{23,24...,70\}  \\
\{22 \}  & \text{if} \: P_A =22  \\
\{x \in \mathbb{Z_+}| x \geq 21 \}  & \text{if} \: P_A =21  \\
\{ x \in \mathbb{Z_+}| x > P_A  \} & \text{if} P_A \leq 20\: 
\end{matrix}\right.$
Nash equilibrium is all those $(P_A^*,P_B^*) \in \{(P_A,P_B) \in \mathbb{Z_+^2}| P_A \in BR_A(P_B) \wedge P_B \in BR_B(P_A) \} $
Verify that the set of nash equilibrium prices is $\{ (21,22),(20,21) ,(19,20),(18,19),(17,18),(16,17),(15,16),(14,15),(13,14),(12,13),(11,12) \}$
Notice that in each Nash equilibrium, firm B sets a higher price and hence its profit is 0 in any Nash equilibria. Maximum profit for firm A (among the nash equilibria) is when $P_A^* = 21$ and $P_B^* = 22$ which is equal to 1089.
Had it been the case that the firm 2 was not present, the monopoly A firm would have charged $P_A = 65 \: \text{with} \: \pi_A = 3025$. This means the maximum firm A would pay to firm B to exit the market is = $3025-1089 = 1936$. Notice, that firm B in Nash equilibrium made 0 profit, so minimum it needs to exit the market is 0.

Since the Marginal cost of firm 1 is $10$, i.e. $\frac{\partial C_A(q)}{\partial q}=10$ and the Marginal cost of firm B is 21, i.e. $\frac{\partial C_B(q)}{\partial q}=21$ and both firms are only allowed to Charge integer prices, so firm A will charge $P=21-1=20$ and will enjoy entire market to itself since firm B cannot produce at this price and make losses, from the demand function we can see that at $P=20, q=100$. Profits of Firm A at $P=20$ are $\pi^A=(20-10)100=1000$
Now if firm B is not in the market then Firm A can serve the market as a monopolist so firm A will produce that quantity at which its Marginal Revenue $MR=120-2q$ will be equal to it's marginal cost $MC=10$ to maximize it's profits, equating the two we get that  $q=55,P=65$ and the profits of Monopolist will be $\pi ^m=(65-10)55=3025$. Notice that $\pi ^m> \pi ^A$ Therefore the maximum amount firm A would be willing to pay to the firm B to exit the market is $\pi ^m- \pi ^A=3025-1000=2025$.
Now maybe you can try to solve part (c) on your own.
